# Installing dlib for an alternate python environment

Tags: python, dlib

I've installed python 3.6 alongside the default python 3.8 on my ubuntu 20.04 macbook pro 3,1 with

```
$ sudo make altinstall
```

I am trying to build dlib for a virtual 3.6 environment with pip, but it is failing to find the header Python.h (See code snippet below).

```
 $ pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.20.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/simon/python/3.6/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wegw26or/dlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wegw26or/dlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-h8drewsj
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-wegw26or/dlib/
  Complete output (238 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'dlib/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.6.8 (default, Jun 15 2020, 10:18:50)
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake /tmp/pip-install-wegw26or/dlib/tools/python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/tmp/pip-install-wegw26or/dlib/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/simon/python/3.6/bin/python -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'
  -- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
  -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Found PythonInterp: /home/simon/python/3.6/bin/python (found version "3.6.8")
  -- Found PythonLibs: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.6m.a
  -- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG
  -- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG - Success
  -- pybind11 v2.2.2
  -- Using CMake version: 3.16.3
  -- Compiling dlib version: 19.20.0
  -- Looking for pthread.h
  -- Looking for pthread.h - found
  -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
  -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
  -- Found Threads: TRUE
  -- Found X11: /usr/include
  -- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
  -- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
  -- Looking for gethostbyname
  -- Looking for gethostbyname - found
  -- Looking for connect
  -- Looking for connect - found
  -- Looking for remove
  -- Looking for remove - found
  -- Looking for shmat
  -- Looking for shmat - found
  -- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
  -- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
  -- Found system copy of libpng: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so
  -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
  -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
  -- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1")
  -- Checking for module 'cblas'
  --   No package 'cblas' found
  -- Checking for module 'lapack'
  --   Found lapack, version 0.3.8+ds
  -- Looking for sys/types.h
  -- Looking for sys/types.h - found
  -- Looking for stdint.h
  -- Looking for stdint.h - found
  -- Looking for stddef.h
  -- Looking for stddef.h - found
  -- Check size of void*
  -- Check size of void* - done
  -- Found OpenBLAS library
  -- Looking for sgetrf_single
  -- Looking for sgetrf_single - found
  -- Using OpenBLAS's built in LAPACK
  -- Looking for cblas_ddot
  -- Looking for cblas_ddot - found
  -- Looking for sgesv
  -- Looking for sgesv - not found
  -- Looking for sgesv_
  -- Looking for sgesv_ - not found
  CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
  -- Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "7.5")
  -- DID NOT FIND CUDA
  -- Disabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL NOT USE CUDA
  -- C++11 activated.
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: /tmp/pip-install-wegw26or/dlib/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  Invoking CMake build: 'cmake --build . --config Release -- -j1'
  Scanning dependencies of target dlib
  [  0%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [  1%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bigint/bigint_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [  2%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bigint/bigint_kernel_2.cpp.o
  [  3%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bit_stream/bit_stream_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [  3%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [  4%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_2.cpp.o
  [  5%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_encoder/entropy_encoder_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [  6%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_encoder/entropy_encoder_kernel_2.cpp.o
  [  6%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/md5/md5_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [  7%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/tokenizer/tokenizer_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [  8%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/unicode/unicode.cpp.o
  [  9%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/test_for_odr_violations.cpp.o
  [ 10%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [ 10%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bsp/bsp.cpp.o
  [ 11%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [ 12%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_kernel_2.cpp.o
  [ 13%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_extensions.cpp.o
  [ 13%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/linker/linker_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [ 14%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/extra_logger_headers.cpp.o
  [ 15%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/logger_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [ 16%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/logger_config_file.cpp.o
  [ 16%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/misc_api/misc_api_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [ 17%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/misc_api/misc_api_kernel_2.cpp.o
  [ 18%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_extensions.cpp.o
  [ 19%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_kernel_2.cpp.o
  [ 20%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockstreambuf/sockstreambuf.cpp.o
  [ 20%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockstreambuf/sockstreambuf_unbuffered.cpp.o
  [ 21%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_kernel.cpp.o
  [ 22%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_iostream.cpp.o
  [ 23%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_http.cpp.o
  [ 23%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/multithreaded_object_extension.cpp.o
  [ 24%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threaded_object_extension.cpp.o
  [ 25%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [ 26%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_2.cpp.o
  [ 26%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_shared.cpp.o
  [ 27%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/thread_pool_extension.cpp.o
  [ 28%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/async.cpp.o
  [ 29%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/timer/timer.cpp.o
  [ 30%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/stack_trace.cpp.o
  [ 30%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/cpu_dlib.cpp.o
  [ 31%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/tensor_tools.cpp.o
  [ 32%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/data_io/image_dataset_metadata.cpp.o
  [ 33%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/data_io/mnist.cpp.o
  [ 33%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/global_optimization/global_function_search.cpp.o
  [ 34%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/filtering/kalman_filter.cpp.o
  [ 35%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/svm/auto.cpp.o
  [ 36%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/fonts.cpp.o
  [ 36%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/widgets.cpp.o
  [ 37%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/drawable.cpp.o
  [ 38%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/canvas_drawing.cpp.o
  [ 39%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/style.cpp.o
  [ 40%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/base_widgets.cpp.o
  [ 40%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_core/gui_core_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [ 41%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_core/gui_core_kernel_2.cpp.o
  [ 42%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_loader/png_loader.cpp.o
  [ 43%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_saver/save_png.cpp.o
  [ 43%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jaricom.c.o
  [ 44%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcapimin.c.o
  [ 45%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcapistd.c.o
  [ 46%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcarith.c.o
  [ 46%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jccoefct.c.o
  [ 47%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jccolor.c.o
  [ 48%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcdctmgr.c.o
  [ 49%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jchuff.c.o
  [ 50%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcinit.c.o
  [ 50%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcmainct.c.o
  [ 51%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcmarker.c.o
  [ 52%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcmaster.c.o
  [ 53%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcomapi.c.o
  [ 53%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcparam.c.o
  [ 54%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcprepct.c.o
  [ 55%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcsample.c.o
  [ 56%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdapimin.c.o
  [ 56%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdapistd.c.o
  [ 57%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdarith.c.o
  [ 58%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdatadst.c.o
  [ 59%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdatasrc.c.o
  [ 60%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdcoefct.c.o
  [ 60%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdcolor.c.o
  [ 61%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jddctmgr.c.o
  [ 62%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdhuff.c.o
  [ 63%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdinput.c.o
  [ 63%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmainct.c.o
  [ 64%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmarker.c.o
  [ 65%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmaster.c.o
  [ 66%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmerge.c.o
  [ 66%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdpostct.c.o
  [ 67%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdsample.c.o
  [ 68%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jerror.c.o
  [ 69%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jfdctflt.c.o
  [ 70%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jfdctfst.c.o
  [ 70%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jfdctint.c.o
  [ 71%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jidctflt.c.o
  [ 72%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jidctfst.c.o
  [ 73%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jidctint.c.o
  [ 73%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jmemmgr.c.o
  [ 74%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jmemnobs.c.o
  [ 75%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jquant1.c.o
  [ 76%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jquant2.c.o
  [ 76%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jutils.c.o
  [ 77%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_loader/jpeg_loader.cpp.o
  [ 78%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_saver/save_jpeg.cpp.o
  [ 79%] Linking CXX static library libdlib.a
  [ 79%] Built target dlib
  Scanning dependencies of target dlib_python
  [ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/dlib.cpp.o
  In file included from /tmp/pip-install-wegw26or/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/pytypes.h:12,
                   from /tmp/pip-install-wegw26or/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/cast.h:13,
                   from /tmp/pip-install-wegw26or/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/attr.h:13,
                   from /tmp/pip-install-wegw26or/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:43,
                   from /tmp/pip-install-wegw26or/dlib/dlib/../dlib/python/pybind_utils.h:6,
                   from /tmp/pip-install-wegw26or/dlib/dlib/../dlib/python.h:6,
                   from /tmp/pip-install-wegw26or/dlib/tools/python/src/opaque_types.h:6,
                   from /tmp/pip-install-wegw26or/dlib/tools/python/src/dlib.cpp:4:
  /tmp/pip-install-wegw26or/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:111:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    111 | #include <Python.h>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/dlib.cpp.o] Error 1
  make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:117: CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/all] Error 2
  make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-wegw26or/dlib/setup.py", line 261, in <module>
      'Topic :: Software Development',
    File "/home/simon/python/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 143, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/src/Python-3.6.8/Lib/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/src/Python-3.6.8/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/src/Python-3.6.8/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/home/simon/python/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 223, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/src/Python-3.6.8/Lib/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/src/Python-3.6.8/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/src/Python-3.6.8/Lib/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/src/Python-3.6.8/Lib/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/src/Python-3.6.8/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-wegw26or/dlib/setup.py", line 135, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "/tmp/pip-install-wegw26or/dlib/setup.py", line 175, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_build, cwd=build_folder)
    File "/usr/src/Python-3.6.8/Lib/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '-j1']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
```

I get the same error if I install dlib v19.8.2.

If I locate Python.h I get

```
$ locate Python.h
/home/simon/Python-3.6.8/Include/Python.h
/usr/include/python3.8/Python.h
/usr/local/include/python3.6m/Python.h
/usr/src/Python-3.6.8/Include/Python.h
/usr/src/Python-3.6.9/Include/Python.h
```

I've tried to install libpython-3.6 and python-3.6 but get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpython3.6-dev python3.6-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libpython3.6-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libpython3.6-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpython3.6-dev'
E: Unable to locate package python3.6-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.6-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.6-dev'
```

But in any case, I have the impression that this is superceded by python3.8-dev so even if I found these, I would not be able to install them:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-dev is already the newest version (3.8.2-0ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

When I build dlib under python 3.8 it works however I need to work with python 3.6 for other reasons. How can I build dlib in my virtual 3.6 environment with my 3.6 Python.h header, please?

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: You mean you built python3.6 from source? Is conda environment good fit for you also? I just have managed to install `dlib` on Ubuntu 20.04 with conda

Comment: Yes. From Python-3.6.8.tgz. I've never used conda to be honest, however if I need to go that way then I will. I'm not very experienced and much more familiar with pip.

Comment: There is almost no overhead using conda and you can still use pip with with conda for installing packages. I will post an answer with conda, hope you will find it useful

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go and feedback how I get on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) for that. You will avoid worrying about environment setup. When you activate a certain environment with `conda activate` (please see below) all relevant environment paths are directed toward the directory of conda environment.

```sh
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
sudo chmod 755 Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

conda create -n py36 python=3.6.10

# you should initialize conda during installation and restart shell after installation to get started with conda or run $ source .bashrc from you home directory


conda activate py36
pip install dlib
```

Of course with the previous set-up of `CMake` and `g++` (or other compiler)

Comment: Perfect! Thank-you!  I needed to run some of the  commands with sudo until I changed permission on the /root directory but it worked.

Comment: @SimonTye I added some comment, regarding your other suggestions. You should be able to initialize conda during installation and by default (just checked) if you request python=3.6 it should get you the highest available python 3.6.x, I am not sure why you ended up with python 3.7. If you think there is still something worth adding, do not hesitate to make suggestions

Comment: I must have made a mistake somewhere although I was pretty careful. I am pretty sure I looked in /root/miniconda3/envs and it was empty, although when I activated the shell py36 came up. When I installed to my home area rather than root to get around any ownership issues the same happened. Using the switch 3.6.10 as you suggested above as opposed to 3.6 seemed to work tho'. No other explanation than I didn't read some error message or something similar... Works now, tho' Thanks!